# How to load a Kivy Application to my iPhone

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I have made a Kivy application but now I would like to run it on my iPhone (I made it using a MacBook). How can I do this? I have already tried following the Kivy "create a package for IOS" instructions the command "toolchain build kivy" simply returns an error saying that "SDK 'iphonesimulator' cannot be located"